# Visual Studio 2013 HRESULT: 0x80131515; HRESULT: 0x80070057

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have a WCF web app that has been building and running under debug until Yesterday.  The problem started when I decided I wanted a Release build to deploy.  The Release was unable to build because of the

> HRESULT: 0x80131515

involving **Newtonsoft.Json.dll**.  But then at the end of the day, **I lost power to my computer** while Visual Studio was running.  Now today, I am getting the same error involving the **AjaxControlToolkit.dll** instead!  But this time it is worse.  Trying to build the Release still creates the previous error code for the **AjaxControlToolkit**.  The debug will still compile, but the page can't run properly and I receive this error from IE:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its
>   dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

I have tried,

1. Clean and Build the solution and each project individually.
2. Unblocking the files (files weren't blocked)
3. Downloading and replacing the AjaxControlToolkit.dll file
4. Clearing the C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ Temporary ASP.NET folder
5. Clearing the C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp folder
6. Restarting the computer
7. Reverting Git to a previous build into a new folder

Nothing has helped.

I would be happy to provide any more information.  Thank you!

Comment: What IIS (IIS Express) framework are you running?

Comment: Ok so..... Now it "works".... for no reason.

Comment: And by "works" I mean that I am back to the point I was yesterday where Debug works properly but Release can't find the library.  Except this time, the AjaxControlToolkit.dll is still the issue instead of Newtonsoft.json.dll.  I'm not gonna call this "fixed" because it's well.... not.  But considering Git didn't seem to help me last time.... I'm kind of afraid to keep messing with it.  The site needs to be demoed next tuesday.  Everything else works, it's just this ridiculous Visual Studio issue.  I might be more aggressive with this after the demo.

Comment: Sounds like your release build wants to drag in a debug DLL that it cannot find. Make sure all your release side code is only using release built DLLs/assemblies/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem has either been solved... or is hiding for another day.  Either way, I can now compile in both debug and release mode!

I was running Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 1.
I am now running Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 4.

Not what I would call a satisfying conclusion... But it works!